# android surfaceview onDraw vs thread.onDraw

Tags: android, surfaceview, ondraw

What is better for a android game to use:

- a `SurfaceView` with a rendering thread

  or
- a `SurfaceView` with a thread that calls the `SurfaceView` function `doDraw()`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawing in a `SurfaceView` is already handled in a separate thread. You do not need to spawn a new one.

See the [API doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) about it:

> One of the purposes of this class is to provide a surface in which a secondary thread can render into the screen. If you are going to use it this way, you need to be aware of some threading semantics:
>
> - All SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder.Callback methods will be called from the thread running the SurfaceView's window (typically the main thread of the application). They thus need to correctly synchronize with any state that is also touched by the drawing thread.
> - You must ensure that the drawing thread only touches the underlying Surface while it is valid -- between SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceCreated() and SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed().

Comment: If you look at the LunarLander example the SurfaceView has a thread (called LunarThread) which has a function called doDraw(), which draws to the canvas. My question is if there is any difference in moving the doDraw function (from the thread) to the SurfaceView class and calling the function from the thread, something like: MySurfaceView.doDraw();

Comment: @jerenj the doDraw() function is just to keep the drawing implementation separated and to improve readability, as it does not create any new thread in it. Regarding creating a `MySurfaceView.doDraw()` method, I would think it will be quite cumbersome to keep it synchronized with the SurfaceHolder. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: The only thing that bothers me is(in the lunar  example) if u keep the lunar X position stored in the LunarThread everytime u'll press home your thread will be terminated and the X position lost. so i thought if i move the draw method to the surfaceview class and call it from LunarThread the problem is solved (because lunarview stores the current X position). Or to move only the lunar variables to lunarview.

Comment: The documentation says "can", not "does" -- I do not believe it is the case that the drawing is handled already in a separate thread.

Comment: Your interpretation of the document is probably not correct, as it says: It allows for a secondary thread to do rendering/drawing. And cautions that if you do go this way, you must take care of synchronization with the main thread.